# How to convert a SQL WITH query to LINQ

Tags: php, linq, wordpress

How can I convert the following sql query using linq. I just want to have a `Row_Number` column and use its values in the linq where clause

```
With t As
(
    Select Row_Number() over ( Order by Id ) as 'RowId', * From Orders
)
Select * From t Where RowId between 1 and 10
```

Comment: What linq library are you using

Comment: Yea, we need to know what PHP Linq library you are using in order to help you - otherwise, I don't think it should be classified as php or wordpress...

Comment: Can you answer the questions in the comments above then flag to re-open. thanks.